# Symfony strips /app from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I'm currently trying to setup Symfony 2 but it's not working as intended.
I got the project via composer (http://symfony.com/download, version 2.5) and created a route /app. Now it turns out it is impossible to access that route in the prod env.
When I go to /app_dev.php/app everything works fine, but /app online redirects me to /.

.htacces file is the default one: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess

I have no clue why it is not working.
If i go to /app/app/app/test it redirects me to /test.
I want to keep the /app and treat it as a normal route. 
Has anyone a solution?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Set /app as in config/routing.yml

Comment: The route is added and works with a /app_dev.php/app

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the cache on the prod environment

```
$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Comment: Bizarre. I wonder if it is because it is named 'app' that it's causing the problem. The reason being that by default, app.php is removed, and considered converted to /. I wonder if it also finds your 'app' and does the same. The upshot, try changing the route name, or remove it altogether

Comment: Changing the route works, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.